# Тип сказуемого в предложении

Tags: сказуемые

**Каковы были причины вашего ухода?**
Я так понимаю, слово *причины* - подлежащее, а вот по поводу сказуемого возникает вопрос. Или это просто *были*, и тогда это простое глагольное, или *каковы были*?
Надеюсь на вашу помощь, и заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Каковы были причины вашего ухода?**
>
> ...по поводу сказуемого возникает вопрос. Или это просто *были*, и
>   тогда это простое глагольное, или *каковы были*?

Верно второе: ***каковы были.***

Сказуемое составное именное, как и в этом предложении:

***Каковы*** причины вашего ухода?